# Swift Combine and SwiftUI understanding needs corrections

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I try do achieve something simple. In AppDelegate I need `var vertices: [SCNVector3] = []`. In `@IBAction func getVertices(_ sender: Any)` I can read file and assign new value to `vertices`. Simple and works. But when I try to pass value to SwiftUI View I have problems.
If I define

```
@State var vertices: [SCNVector3] = []

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    ....
    let contentView = CloudView(data: $vertices)
    ....
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    ...
}

@IBAction func getVertices(_ sender: Any) {
    ...
    do {
        let readVertices: [SCNVector3] = try... // read file and convert to [SCNVector3]
        vertcices = readVertices // assign or not to assign, this is a question
        print (readVertices.count, vertices.count)
    }
    ...
}
```

and it prints:

```
3500 0
```

so, it never updates `CloudView`, `vertices` is always an empty array.

Could somebody explain me how I should do it in proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `@State` outside of SwiftUI view context. In this scenario most appropriate will be to use `ObservableObject`, like

```
class VerticesStorage: ObservableObject {
   @Published var vertices: [SCNVector3] = []
}
```

then in AppDelegate

```
let verticesStorage = VerticesStorage()   // initialize property

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    ....
    let contentView = CloudView(data: verticesStorage) // inject reference
    ....
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    ...
}

@IBAction func getVertices(_ sender: Any) {
    ...
    do {
        let readVertices: [SCNVector3] = try... // read file and convert to [SCNVector3]

        verticesStorage.vertcices = readVertices // update here !!

        print (readVertices.count, vertices.count)
    }
    ...
}
```

and now in SwiftUI part

```
struct CloudView: View {
   @ObservedObject var data: VerticesStorage     // observable !!

   var body: some View {
     // present here
   }
}
```